# My foreach won't make a call for every coordinate that I pass

Tags: php, curl, geocoding

I pass some coordinates to my foreach to a reverse geocoding. I get only one coordinate but not them all. I think it's a problem of delay. 
Here's my code:

```
foreach ($coordPointsArray as $coordPointArray) {
  $latLangCoords = implode(",", $coordPointArray);
  echo($latLangCoords);
  $callToGoogleGeocode = curl_init();
  $urlGeocode = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='. urlencode($latLangCoords). '&key=' . $googleApiKey;
  curl_setopt_array($callToGoogleGeocode, [
      CURLOPT_URL            => $urlGeocode,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  => "GET",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => [
          "cache-control: no-cache"
      ],
  ]);
  $rawResponseGeocode = curl_exec($callToGoogleGeocode);
}
return($rawResponseGeocode);
```

here's the echo response:

```
45.4807897,9.21359845.4801858,9.214740945.4801858,9.214740945.4763715,9.21103245.4763715,9.21103245.4748449,9.211080445.4748449,9.211080445.4685044,9.211260645.4685044,9.211260645.4673681,9.211252645.4673681,9.211252645.4621453,9.211394845.4621453,9.211394845.4621861,9.20949345.4621861,9.20949345.4604364,9.2092372
```

Comment: What do you expect it to return? The last line in the foreach loop overwrites the variable each time so you return the last value.

Comment: how do i fix it?

Comment: Again, what do you want the function to return? If you want an array of coordinates, make an array and return that.

Comment: I want to make a call with every coordinate that i loop in the foreach

Comment: And return every call that i made

Answer (score 0):

I did a mistake. I was overwriting the variable at the end. I needed to store my responses in an array with array push.